# Multiple OR condition is not working in SQL join query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I am trying to get the data from sql join query. The query is not working when I use date filter with 3 combinations in where clause.

```
 IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempAllocStatus1') IS NOT NULL
                         DROP TABLE #tempAllocStatus1 

                         SELECT  Users.Name,REPLACE(Staff.Designation, 'IND ', '') as Designation, Staff.Office as Location,
                                        (SELECT  COUNT(ReqDt.ID) FROM tblTPRequestDetail ReqDt  
                                        INNER JOIN  tblTPRequest Req ON ReqDt.RequestID = Req.Id 
                                        WHERE ReqDt.AssignedToID = Users.UserADID AND Req.TypeOfRequest = 1 AND ((ReqDt.StatusCode = 'COMP' or ReqDt.StatusCode = 'PCR') or (ReqDt.StatusCode = 'AWIP' and ReqDt.SubStatusCode='BENRE' or ReqDt.SubStatusCode='BENSF' or ReqDt.SubStatusCode='DRR' or ReqDt.SubStatusCode='DRSO' or ReqDt.SubStatusCode='RPSOFF'))) [Indian Benchmarking Assigned], 

                                        (SELECT  COUNT(ReqDt.ID) FROM tblTPRequestDetail ReqDt  
                                        INNER JOIN  tblTPRequest Req ON ReqDt.RequestID = Req.Id 
                                        WHERE ReqDt.ReviewerID = Users.UserADID AND Req.TypeOfRequest = 1 AND ((ReqDt.StatusCode = 'COMP' or ReqDt.StatusCode = 'PCR') or (ReqDt.StatusCode = 'AWIP' and ReqDt.SubStatusCode='BENSF' or ReqDt.SubStatusCode='DRSO' or ReqDt.SubStatusCode='RPSOFF' or SubStatusCode='RPC' or SubStatusCode='TPRPC'))) [Indian Benchmarking Reviewer], 

                                        (SELECT  COUNT(ReqDt.ID) FROM tblTPRequestDetail ReqDt  
                                        INNER JOIN  tblTPRequest Req ON ReqDt.RequestID = Req.Id 
                                        WHERE ReqDt.SignoffID = Users.UserADID AND Req.TypeOfRequest = 1 AND ((ReqDt.StatusCode = 'COMP' or ReqDt.StatusCode = 'PCR') or (ReqDt.StatusCode = 'AWIP' and ReqDt.SubStatusCode='RPSOFF' or ReqDt.SubStatusCode='SCPC' or ReqDt.SubStatusCode='TPSCPC'))) [Indian Benchmarking Signoff],

                                        (SELECT  COUNT(ReqDt.ID) FROM tblTPRequestDetail ReqDt  
                                        INNER JOIN  tblTPRequest Req ON ReqDt.RequestID = Req.Id 
                                        WHERE ReqDt.AssignedToID = Users.UserADID AND Req.TypeOfRequest = 1 AND ((ReqDt.StatusCode = 'COMP' or ReqDt.StatusCode = 'PCR') or (ReqDt.StatusCode = 'AWIP' and ReqDt.SubStatusCode='BENRE' or ReqDt.SubStatusCode='BENSF' or ReqDt.SubStatusCode='DRR' or ReqDt.SubStatusCode='DRSO' or ReqDt.SubStatusCode='RPSOFF'))) + 
                                        (SELECT  COUNT(ReqDt.ID) FROM tblTPRequestDetail ReqDt  
                                        INNER JOIN  tblTPRequest Req ON ReqDt.RequestID = Req.Id 
                                        WHERE ReqDt.ReviewerID = Users.UserADID AND Req.TypeOfRequest = 1 AND ((ReqDt.StatusCode = 'COMP' or ReqDt.StatusCode = 'PCR') or (ReqDt.StatusCode = 'AWIP' and ReqDt.SubStatusCode='BENSF' or ReqDt.SubStatusCode='DRSO' or ReqDt.SubStatusCode='RPSOFF' or SubStatusCode='RPC' or SubStatusCode='TPRPC'))) + 
                                        (SELECT  COUNT(ReqDt.ID) FROM tblTPRequestDetail ReqDt  
                                        INNER JOIN  tblTPRequest Req ON ReqDt.RequestID = Req.Id 
                                        WHERE ReqDt.SignoffID = Users.UserADID AND Req.TypeOfRequest = 1 AND ((ReqDt.StatusCode = 'COMP' or ReqDt.StatusCode = 'PCR') or (ReqDt.StatusCode = 'AWIP' and ReqDt.SubStatusCode='RPSOFF' or ReqDt.SubStatusCode='SCPC' or ReqDt.SubStatusCode='TPSCPC'))) [Indian Benchmarking Total],


                           (SELECT  COUNT(ReqDt.ID) FROM tblTPRequestDetail ReqDt 
                            WHERE ReqDt.AssignedToID = Users.UserADID AND ((ReqDt.StatusCode = 'COMP' or ReqDt.StatusCode = 'PCR') or (ReqDt.StatusCode = 'AWIP' and ReqDt.SubStatusCode='BENRE' or ReqDt.SubStatusCode='BENSF' or ReqDt.SubStatusCode='DRR' or ReqDt.SubStatusCode='DRSO' or ReqDt.SubStatusCode='RPSOFF'))) [All Assigned], 
                            (SELECT  COUNT(ReqDt.ID) FROM tblTPRequestDetail ReqDt 
                            WHERE ReqDt.ReviewerID = Users.UserADID AND ((ReqDt.StatusCode = 'COMP' or ReqDt.StatusCode = 'PCR') or (ReqDt.StatusCode = 'AWIP' and ReqDt.SubStatusCode='BENSF' or ReqDt.SubStatusCode='DRSO' or ReqDt.SubStatusCode='RPSOFF' or SubStatusCode='RPC' or SubStatusCode='TPRPC'))) [All Reviewer], 
                            (SELECT  COUNT(ReqDt.ID) FROM tblTPRequestDetail ReqDt 
                            INNER JOIN  tblTPRequest Req ON ReqDt.RequestID = Req.Id 
                            WHERE ReqDt.SignoffID = Users.UserADID AND ((ReqDt.StatusCode = 'COMP' or ReqDt.StatusCode = 'PCR') or (ReqDt.StatusCode = 'AWIP' and ReqDt.SubStatusCode='RPSOFF' or ReqDt.SubStatusCode='SCPC' or ReqDt.SubStatusCode='TPSCPC'))) [All Signoff],
                            (SELECT  COUNT(ReqDt.ID) FROM tblTPRequestDetail ReqDt 
                            WHERE ReqDt.AssignedToID = Users.UserADID AND ((ReqDt.StatusCode = 'COMP' or ReqDt.StatusCode = 'PCR') or (ReqDt.StatusCode = 'AWIP' and ReqDt.SubStatusCode='BENRE' or ReqDt.SubStatusCode='BENSF' or ReqDt.SubStatusCode='DRR' or ReqDt.SubStatusCode='DRSO' or ReqDt.SubStatusCode='RPSOFF'))) + 
                            (SELECT  COUNT(ReqDt.ID) FROM tblTPRequestDetail ReqDt 
                            WHERE ReqDt.ReviewerID = Users.UserADID AND ((ReqDt.StatusCode = 'COMP' or ReqDt.StatusCode = 'PCR') or (ReqDt.StatusCode = 'AWIP' and ReqDt.SubStatusCode='BENSF' or ReqDt.SubStatusCode='DRSO' or ReqDt.SubStatusCode='RPSOFF' or SubStatusCode='RPC' or SubStatusCode='TPRPC'))) + 
                            (SELECT  COUNT(ReqDt.ID) FROM tblTPRequestDetail ReqDt 
                            INNER JOIN  tblTPRequest Req ON ReqDt.RequestID = Req.Id 
                            WHERE ReqDt.SignoffID = Users.UserADID AND ((ReqDt.StatusCode = 'COMP' or ReqDt.StatusCode = 'PCR') or (ReqDt.StatusCode = 'AWIP' and ReqDt.SubStatusCode='RPSOFF' or ReqDt.SubStatusCode='SCPC' or ReqDt.SubStatusCode='TPSCPC'))) [All Total]

                            INTO #tempAllocStatus1

                            FROM tblUserRolesMapping Users

                                LEFT JOIN [tblstaff] Staff ON Users.UserADID = Staff.AD_Id                                  
                                LEFT JOIN tblTPRequestDetail UserAssigned ON UserAssigned.AssignedToID = Users.UserADID
                                LEFT JOIN tblTPRequestDetail UserReviewer ON UserReviewer.ReviewerID = Users.UserADID
                                LEFT JOIN tblTPRequestDetail UserSignoff ON UserSignoff.SignoffID = Users.UserADID

                                LEFT JOIN tblTPRequest TPRAssigned ON UserAssigned.RequestID = TPRAssigned.ID
                                LEFT JOIN tblTPRequest TPRReviewer ON UserReviewer.RequestID = TPRReviewer.ID
                                LEFT JOIN tblTPRequest TPRSignoff ON UserSignoff.RequestID = TPRSignoff.ID 

                            WHERE Users.Active = 1 and Users.[RoleId] !=6
                                      AND TPRAssigned.crtddate >= '2017-04-01'  and TPRAssigned.crtddate<= '2017-05-30'

                                      OR TPRReviewer.crtddate >= '2017-04-01'  AND TPRReviewer.crtddate<='2017-05-30'

                                      OR TPRSignoff.crtddate >= '2017-04-01'  AND TPRSignoff.crtddate<='2017-05-30' 
                                       GROUP BY Users.UserADID,  Users.Name, Staff.Designation,Staff.Office 

                                SELECT * FROM #tempAllocStatus1 WHERE [All Total] > 0

                                    UNION ALL

                                SELECT * FROM #tempAllocStatus1 WHERE [All Total] = 0
```

And I am facing the issue in the below lines of the query.

```
                             AND TPRAssigned.crtddate >= '2017-04-01'  and TPRAssigned.crtddate<= '2017-05-30'

                                      OR TPRReviewer.crtddate >= '2017-04-01'  AND TPRReviewer.crtddate<='2017-05-30'

                                      OR TPRSignoff.crtddate >= '2017-04-01'  AND TPRSignoff.crtddate<='2017-05-30'
```

If I use any 2 combination of dates, its working fine. If I add the third condition of date, its loading for long time and not getting any data. Please help.

Comment: I suggest you also ask a separate question about "How can I simplify this query"? All those correlated sub queries will be costing you a fortune in resources, and can be replaced by simple joins and case statements.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular-formatted base table initialization. For SQL performance that includes EXPLAIN results & statistics. PS Clearly there is non-minimal code.

Comment: Learn what LEFT JOIN ON returns: INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN. A WHERE or INNER JOIN ON that requires a right [sic] table column to be not NULL after an OUTER JOIN ON removes any rows extended by NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN ON rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that. PS "is not working" tells us nothing. PS Now that you have a helpful answer please ask a new question. With a [mre]. PS Speed is irrelevant while the code is wrong.

Comment: I have asked a separate question about "How to simplify the query". Please help me. URL is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58094354/how-can-i-simplify-the-sql-query

Answer (score 2):

You have an order of operations problem, because `AND` is *higher* precedence than `OR`.  Use parentheses to impose the logic you intend:

```
WHERE
    ... AND
    (TPRAssigned.crtddate BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND '2017-05-30') OR
    (TPRReviewer.crtddate BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND '2017-05-30') OR
    (TPRSignoff.crtddate BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND '2017-05-30')
```

Note that your current logic is actually being evaluated as:

```
(TPRAssigned.crtddate >= '2017-04-01' AND TPRAssigned.crtddate <= '2017-05-30') OR
(TPRReviewer.crtddate >= '2017-04-01' AND TPRReviewer.crtddate <= '2017-05-30') OR
(TPRSignoff.crtddate >= '2017-04-01'  AND TPRSignoff.crtddate <= '2017-05-30')
```

Most likely, this is not the logic you want.

Comment: I have tried these methods also. But its also loading for a long time and it gets timeout

Comment: @user3581029 The performance of your query is another topic, not what you asked.  I fixed your logic.

Comment: I have already tried these methods with parentheses. With or without Parenthesis, the 2 combinations were working. Even though with Parenthesis, the third OR condition is not working. As I mentioned in my query, its loading for long time and not getting any data

Comment: Your query is pretty massive, and I'm not in a good position to suggest optimizations.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Anyone else can please help me with this issue.

Comment: As a hint, the correlated subqueries in your select clause are most likely what is killing your performance.   You should rewrite them using a join to the `tblTPRequestDetail` table.